# What is the parameter for CLI YOLOv8 predict to use Intel GPU?

Tags: gpu, opencl, intel, yolov8

I installed OpenVINO dependencies and converted the model to OpenVINO format. I have OpenCL device available:

```
$ clinfo -l
Platform #0: Intel(R) OpenCL HD Graphics
 `-- Device #0: Intel(R) Graphics [0xa7a0]
```

Trying to run `yolo predict` on a GPU, e.g.

```
yolo predict model=openvino_model source='samples/*.jpg' device=gpu
yolo predict model=openvino_model source='samples/*.jpg' device=0
```

always results in `Invalid CUDA device requested`. It runs fine on the CPU, though.

What parameter should I use for yolo to find and use OpenCL device #0?